# Loading multi-component bytes into shader in Vulkan

Tags: glsl, vulkan

Vulkan allows you to specify attributes as multi-component byte arrays such as with the qualifier "VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UINT". I am, however, unsure what input variable type I should use in my glsl shader. Using an ivec3 creates an error as I would expect.

Do I need to load them into an **uint** and then do bitwise operations do extract the variables? What are the speed implications of this?

If I want to do these bitwise operations, how can I be sure they will be endian-independent? To my understanding, the first byte on my CPU side could be stored in the first or last byte of the integer on the GPU side.

Comment: ```VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8_UINT specifies a three-component, 24-bit unsigned integer format that has an 8-bit R component in byte 0, an 8-bit G component in byte 1, and an 8-bit B component in byte 2.``` So in my opinion a vec3 of uint8_t should work.

Comment: glsl doesn't have a vec3 of uint8_t, does it? @Linkthehero2222

Comment: You can use ```glm::vec</*number of numbers*/ 3, /*typename*/ uint8_t, defaultp>```

Comment: My question is about what my input variable type should be **in my glsl shader** and not in my CPU code

Comment: my bad with uvec3

Comment: how do I extract the bytes? is there endianness I need to consider? etc. I have specified this in my question now too

Comment: you just have uvec3, the gpu should extract the values and put them inside the vector components on its own

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to "extract". You asked to pass 3 unsigned integer values per-vertex. That's what the format defines, and that's what the shader should receive. The fact that each unsigned integer value is 8 bits doesn't need to be reflected in your shader; only that they're unsigned integers and that there are 3 of them.

There are no endian issues; not unless you *create* them in your CPU code. The format specifies that each value of the attribute comes from an array of 3 8-bit values. The three components are read left-to-right, and that's the order the components are expected to be in in memory.

Bytes don't have endian problems. Endian only is an issue when reading a *single value* that takes up multiple bytes. You asked to read 3 bytes, so that's what it will do. And that's what the CPU should write.

BTW, you should avoid using misaligned types like this. Pad it out to 4 8-bit integers rather than 3.